# MS Graph API - AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-ad-graph-api

A recurring job has started to fail, I've recreated the issue with Postman.

Error:

```
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password."
"error_codes": [50126]
"error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"
```

The Username & Password used, work with MS Graph Explorer so I'm confident that the password has not changed. I did change the `grant_type=client_credentials` and this works so I believe the rest of the settings are also correct. I did ramp up the frequency of the job from daily to hourly lately, but the error message indicates an authentication issue.

I'm running out of ideas to try & troubleshoot, perhaps someone knows something that I don't.

Postman settings:
[image: Postman settings]

These are the production settings used in MS Power Automate, the same as above.

[image: MS Graph PowerAutomate]

Comment: Is your account MFA-enabled?

Comment: I dont believe the account has MFA enabled as it's a system account but I will investigate

Comment: Make sure your `UserName` and `Password` is correct though you are confident instead I would tell try changing them once again.

Comment: I've extracted the AD User -Properties & the password has not been changed. I''ve also had the account activity extracted, It's displaying failures with the above application but Successes for Office365, OWA & Graph explorer, all using the same password. I will commit to changing the password if I do not have this resolved in a day or two. But many other automated processes use this account so it's going to be a last resort. Thank you for the suggestion I'm open to anything as it's really puzzling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**: Authentication error when trying to authenticate to MS Graph API with an AD account that had previously worked.

**Final Hypothesise**: A potential issue between cloud authentication & on-prem AD authentication.

**Solution**: A new AzureAD service account specifically for the purpose was created & provisioned with similar access to the original service account & all worked as normal.

**Summary**: The issue seems to have been the link between AzureAD & on-premAD. Hope this helps someone out in future

Answer (score 1):

If its  an unattended process and uses the [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) flow, then the username and password are not being used at all.

An Access token is being obtained using the clientId and the client secret alone.

It'd help if you can list the operations that you are planning to call in the question.

Note that MS Graph uses both [delegated and application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#microsoft-graph-permissions) and depending on the Api being called, you would be required to sign-in as an app of sign-in a user. Its a bit of a learning curve and I'd recommend you go through a session like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBbnpFdB92A).

Comment: The process uses delegated permissions & was working for the past 2 months before the error began a few days ago. I switched to client credentials to test that the client secret had not expired. As the process worked with client credentials and not password it leads me to believe that a setting has changed with the account

Comment: Most probably the Password changed. Try login to Azure portal using those credentials to check if the password is still valid

Comment: Thanks Kalyan, I've extracted the AD User -Properties & the password has not been changed. I've also had the account activity extracted from Azure AD, It's displaying failures with the above application but Successes for Office365, OWA & Graph explorer, when I've tested logging in using the same password.

Comment: In this case you'd need to inspect the traffic (logs). See if you can use a tool like fiddler to accurately check what's being sent in requests. Is it the right tenant? Is the user being authenticated for an Api that requires and app only token.

Comment: I'll look into Fiddler, thanks! The app was working until this Monday so I'm checking all areas, it's probably an admin that's ticked a box but finding the area to spot the admin is keeping me busy during the lockdown. Thanks again for the fiddler suggestion & traffic logs